# Сохранение анимации при height:auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброе утро! Столкнулся с проблемой: когда ставлю параметр в JS height:auto пропадают все эффекты анимации в спойлере. Пробывал различные способы, никак не хочет взаимодействовать JS с данной функцией. Есть ли какие то варианты решения проблемы с соблюдением height:auto но без потери анимации скрытия/открытия слайдера? Спасибо заранее.

```js
 text.style.height = "100px"; //проблема тут, когда ставлю 200px анимация работает, но как только устанавливаю height:auto , анимация слетает
```

Полный код как оно срабатывает на данный момент:

```js
function hasClass(elem, className) { // проверка на hasClass
  return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}

function spoiler(el) {
  var text = el.parentNode.querySelector(".spoilerText"); // находим .spoilerText в полученном элементе 

  if (!hasClass(text, 'active')) {
    text.style.height = "100px"; //проблема тут, когда ставлю 200px анимация работает, но как только устанавливаю height:auto , анимация слетает
    text.classList.add('active');

  } else {
    text.style.height = "0px";
    text.classList.remove('active');
  }

}
```

```css
.spoilerButton {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.spoilerButton:hover {
  background: red;
}

.spoilerText {
  width: 70%;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background: #0081d7;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: left;
}

span {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
      <span>Click for open</span>
    </div>
    <div class="spoilerText">
      <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
        <span>Click for open</span>
      </div>
      <div class="spoilerText">
        <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
          <span>Click for open</span>
        </div>
        <div class="spoilerText">
          <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="text">
          <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
            <span>Click for open</span>
          </div>
          <div class="spoilerText">
            <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: height: auto не понимает ни js, ни transition, единственный вариант: высчитывать нужную высоту - анимировать до неё, потом ставить height: auto. Либо оперировать max-height

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо за ответ, но как это можно реализовать с помощью одной функции JS которая имеет значение каждой из ячеек, а высота в каждой будет отличаться соответственно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через `max-height` (css метод):

```js
function spoiler(el) {
  var text = el.parentNode.querySelector(".spoilerText");

  text.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.spoilerButton {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.spoilerButton:hover {
  background: red;
}

.spoilerText {
  width: 70%;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background: #0081d7;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: left;
}

span {
  font-family: arial;
}

/* Нужные стили */

.spoilerText {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.spoilerText.active {
  /* тут надо понимать, что он будет время растягивать 
  *  на все это расстояние
  *  соответственно для большей "отзывчиваости",
  *  надо задавать размер максимально приближенный
  *  к реальному макс значению
  */
  max-height: 1000px;
}

/* Стили заданы только для того, что бы анимация более менее гладко протекала */
.spoilerText span {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
      <span>Click for open</span>
    </div>
    <div class="spoilerText">
      <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
        <span>Click for open</span>
      </div>
      <div class="spoilerText">
        <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
          <span>Click for open</span>
        </div>
        <div class="spoilerText">
          <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="text">
          <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
            <span>Click for open</span>
          </div>
          <div class="spoilerText">
            <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, первый вариант с CSS отлично подошел!

Comment: Поделил бы на 2 ответа.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ready xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev, вижу :)

Answer (score 2):

Через высчитывание высоты и в дальнейшем `height: auto` (не силен в чистом js, был бы рад, если знатоки поправят):

```js
spoilerInit();

function spoilerInit() {
  const spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName('spoiler')
  
  for(let spoiler of spoilers) {
    const button = spoiler.querySelector('.spoiler_button');
    
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      toggleSpoiler(spoiler);
    });
  }
}

function toggleSpoiler( spoiler ) {
  const content = spoiler.querySelector('.spoiler_content'),
    contentInner = content.querySelector('.spoiler_content-inner'),
    contentInnerHeight = contentInner.clientHeight;
    
  if(spoiler.classList.contains('active')) {
    content.style.height = `${contentInnerHeight}px`;
    
    // Вот это возможно костыль
    setTimeout(function() {
      content.style.height = 0;
      spoiler.classList.remove('active');
    }, 5);
  } else {
    content.style.height = `${contentInnerHeight}px`;

    /* опять же, возможно неидеальный вариант, таймаут привязывать
    *  к css анимации неочень верно, но "йа разработчик, йа так вижу"
    */
    setTimeout(function() {
      content.style.height = 'auto';
      spoiler.classList.add('active');
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

```css
.spoiler {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.spoiler_button {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

.spoiler_button:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.spoiler_content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .3s;
}

.spoiler_content-inner {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spoiler_content-inner p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <button class="spoiler_button">Click for open</button>
  <div class="spoiler_content">
    <div class="spoiler_content-inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <button class="spoiler_button">Click for open</button>
  <div class="spoiler_content">
    <div class="spoiler_content-inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <button class="spoiler_button">Click for open</button>
  <div class="spoiler_content">
    <div class="spoiler_content-inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <button class="spoiler_button">Click for open</button>
  <div class="spoiler_content">
    <div class="spoiler_content-inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```